# How to display the values filled in a contact form as they fill in?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to display the values entered by the user using a contact form at the side of the form. Once they fill in a field it should show the value in the respective place in wordpress..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular JS with wordpress to do so